# Confused with the proof that $S^2-D$ is equidecomposable with $S^2$, where $D$ is a countable set and $S^2$ denotes the unit sphere

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am in the process of reading through the proof of Banach-Tarski paradox and I'm trying to understand it. The paradox requires the proof that $S^2-D$ is equidecomposable with $S^2$, where $D$ is a countable set and $S^2$ denotes the unit sphere. I've seen a lot of articles about this paradox and nearly all of them prove that $S^2-D$ is equidecomposable with $S^2$ in the same way and a way that makes me confused.

The proofs use a line, $l$, through the origin that does not intersect $D$ and then using an angle $\alpha$ such that rotation with $\alpha$ about $l$ never maps a point in $D$ onto another point in $D$. The proofs then define a set $E$ as follows
$E = D \;\cup p(D) \; \cup \; p^2(D) \; \cup \; p^3(D) \cup\cdots$ where $p$ denotes the rotation by $\alpha$. $S^2 = E \; \cup \; (S^2-E)$ which is equidecomposable with $p(E) \; \cup \;(S^2-E) = S^2-D$. 
Which means that $S^2-D$ is equidecomposable with $S^2$. I am really confused with this proof and I have spent hours trying to understand it. Why does this proof use an angle, $\alpha$, so that a rotation by it never maps a point in $D$ to another point in $D$? Wouldn't any angle satisfy the algebra and the equations behind the proof? My guess is that the angle is a "steppingstone" to then proceed with Hilbert's hotel paradox, where the points in $D$ are filled with points further on. However, I can't see that the Hilbert's hotel "trick" is being used here, which makes me question why any angle can't be used.

Comment: The restriction on $\alpha$ is needed to justify the equation $p(E)\cup(S^2-E)=S^2-D$. Without the restriction, $p(E)$ might contain some points from $D$. (Incidentally, your equation on the preceding line has a typo. It should be $S^2=E\cup(S^2-E)$.)

Comment: @Andreas Okay, I think I understand now! So if $\alpha$ would map a point in $D$ to another point in $D$, then $p(D)$ and $p(E)$ could contain some point from $D$. This would mean that $p(E) \cup (S^2 - E) = p(D) \cup p^2(D) \cdots \cup (S^2 - (D \cup p(D) \cup p^2(D) \cdots)) = (S^2 - D) \cup p(D) \cup p^2(D) \cdots$ would not equal to $S^2 - D$ because $p(D), p^2(D) \cdots$ contains points which are not in $S^2 - D$. Does this sound correct? I'm still a dumb 17 year old so please bear with me.